# On Sorli's Conjecture Re: OPNs (Circa 2003)

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, perfect-numbers

In the PhD dissertation titled "Algorithms in the Study of Multiperfect and Odd Perfect Numbers" ([hyperlinked here](http://utsescholarship.lib.uts.edu.au/dspace/handle/2100/275?show=full)) and completed in 2003, Ronald Sorli conjectured that the exponent $k$ on the Euler prime $p$ for an odd perfect number $N = (p^k)(m^2)$ is one (i.e. we can drop $k$).

Assuming Sorli's conjecture is true, does anyone know if there exist (any) "effective" results  (pardon my use of the term, I just could not think of a better word) in the literature, particularly with respect to relations between the Euler prime $p$, the exponent $k$ and the number $\sqrt{\frac{N}{p^k}}$?  I have, so far, only been able to get hold of Paolo Starni's article titled "Odd Perfect Numbers: A Divisor Related to the Euler′s Factor".

In particular, note that Sorli's conjecture implies the following relations:

$$I(p^k) = I(p) = \frac{p+1}{p}$$

$$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p)} = \frac{2p}{p + 1}$$

which, in turn, gives the (trivial) algebraic identity:

$$\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{p+1} + \frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{1}{p+1}\right)$$

where $p$ is the Euler prime (i.e. $p^k$ is the Euler's Factor) and $$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$ is the abundancy index of $x$.

[Edit (September 18 2013) - Per Professor Beasley's paper titled "Euler and the Ongoing Search for Odd Perfect Numbers" from this [hyperlink](http://godandmath.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/acms-2013-proceedings.pdf):

> Before proceeding with Euler’s proof, we pause to note that his result was not quite what
>   Descartes and Frenicle had conjectured, as they believed that $k = 1$, but it came very
>   close. In fact, current research continues in an effort to prove $k = 1$. For example, 
>   Dris has made progress in this direction, although his paper refers to Descartes’ and 
>   Frenicle’s claim (that $k = 1$) as Sorli’s conjecture; Dickson has documented 
>   Descartes’s conjecture as occurring in a letter to Marin Mersenne in 1638, with
>   Frenicle’s subsequent observation occurring in 1657.

End Edit.]

Comment: Consider the sum $I(p^k)+I(m^2)$. Then we have the (sharp) bounds $L(p)=\frac{3p^2−4p+2}{p(p−1)}$ and $U(p)=\frac{3p^2+2p+1}{p(p+1)}$ with $L(p) \lt I(p^k)+I(m^2) \le U(p)$. If Sorli's conjecture is proved, then $I(p^k)+I(m^2)=U(p)$.

Comment: Additionally, the derivative $U'(p) \gt 0$ and, while $U(p)$ has no maximum value on the interval $[5, \infty)$, it does have a least upper bound of $\lim_{p\to\infty}{U(p)} = 3$.  As remarked by Joshua Zelinksy a few years back:  "Any improvement on the upper bound of $3$ would have similar implications for all arbitrarily large primes and thus would be a very major result."  (e.g. $U(p) < 2.99$ implies $p \le 97$.)  Thus, (assuming Sorli's conjecture), "heuristically" we can have the following approach for the OPN problem: Fix an upper bound for $u = U(p)$, and then use factor chains...

Comment: ... to loop until you get the contradiction $U^{-1}(p) < p$.

Comment: Update: If Sorli's conjecture is indeed true, then there are no odd perfect numbers. The proof proceeds via reductio ad absurdum, and is replete with all sorts of contradictions at every (succeeding) step. This reminds me of James Joseph Sylvester's quote from 1888: "… a prolonged meditation on the subject has satisfied me that the existence of any one such [OPN] — its escape, so to say, from the complex web of conditions which hem it in on all sides — would be little short of a miracle."

Comment: Arnie, that is a bold claim.  You really should back it up.  To claim that if $k=1$ there are no OPN's would be a very big deal.

Comment: @Pace, here is the argument.  Suppose there is an OPN $N$ in Eulerian form $N = {p^k}{m^2}$ (i.e. $p \equiv k \equiv 1 (mod 4)$ AND $gcd(p, m) = 1$).  Since all prime-powers are deficient, $p \ne m$.  Case 1:  $m < p$.  Trivially, $p \le {p^k}$.  But in 2008, I proved that ${p^k} < {\frac{2}{3}}{m^2}$.  Thus:  $p \le {p^k} < {p^2}$, which gives you $k = 1$ (since $k \equiv 1 (mod 4)$).  Case 2:  $p < m$.  By treating the result in case 1 via a contrapositive, you get $p^k < m$.  Now, since the two conditions $p \le {p^k} < m$ and $m < p \le {p^k}$ are mutually exclusive (& the corresponding...

Comment: "conditions"/"results" that we want to prove for $k$ are likewise mutually exclusive, then the ONLY way to avoid contradictions in this argument will be to take this result as true: If there is an OPN (again in Eulerian form), then $k > 1$.  This is because, if you assume Sorli's conjecture is true, then you will get a contradiction which goes like:  Fix an Euler prime $p$.  Then compute $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ (as defined above).  Since (i) assuming Sorli's conjecture means that the sum $I(p^k) + I(m^2)$ attains the upper bound $U(p)$ (but never attains the lower bound), and (ii) because assuming..

Comment: ... an "admissible" Euler prime $p$ results in an "inadmissible" Euler prime $p'$ (note that $p$ is supposed to be the same as $p'$) [in the sense that computing for integers $p'$ such that $L(p') < u$ where $u = U(p)$ gives you $p' < p$], we get the implication:  *** Sorli's conjecture implies the OPN conjecture ***.  Thus, Case 2 is what remains to be tackled in order to prove the OPN conjecture in full generality.  But note that, you now have a complete characterization for perfect numbers.  To summarize:  Let $M = (q^a)(n^2)$ be a perfect number (even AND odd).  Then we have:  

Comment: $M$ is even if and only if $a = 1$. Equivalently: $M$ is odd if and only if $a > 1$. This "enhanced" model 
fits everything that is known so far about OPNs, and in fact, it extends the Euclid-Euler model for perfect 
numbers, in the sense that there is a "bifurcation" between the even and odd cases.  Case in point: 
The Mersenne prime is $\equiv 3 (mod 4)$. On the other hand, the Euler prime is $\equiv 1 (mod 4)$. 
If you'd like to know more, you can take a look at 
http://arnienumbers.blogspot.com/2010/12/proof-for-sorlis-conjecture-on-odd.html.

Comment: @Pace, of course, if you are bold enough, you can try proving Sorli's conjecture, and thereby prove the OPN conjecture.  But I am inclined to suggest proving finiteness of OPNs first (see this related MO post: <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48215/re-mordells-equation-y2-x3-k>).

Comment: @Pace, I forgot to mention:  My motivation for pursuing Sorli's conjecture was because of

$$I(M_r) = \frac{M_r + 1}{M_r}$$

$$I((1/2)(M_r + 1)) = \frac{2(M_r)}{M_r + 1}$$

where $M_r$ is THE Mersenne prime with exponent $r$.

Comment: @Pace, in addition, I may have made a "serious" error with that "$L(p')<u=U(p)$ implies $p'<p$". Indeed, it 
suffices to show that, by fixing $u$, $L(p')<u=U(p)$ implies $p' \ne p$ and then treating the case 
$p' = p = 5$ separately. Quite nicely, the last stumbling block to my argument is the lowest possible Euler 
prime! :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no such effective bounds.  In fact, even if $p=5$ and $k=1$, there are no known effective bounds on $N$.  (There are bounds on $N$ in terms of the number of distinct factors.)

Comment: @Pace, thanks a lot!  What about if we consider the sum $$I(p^k) + I(m^2)$$ with this additional information from Sorli's conjecture?  Can you comment on that one?

Comment: I usually think of I as a multiplicative function.  But I imagine that you can use the identities you derived above to get a lower bound on this thing.  But again, if $p=5$ and $k=1$ this sum is just $6/5 + 5/3$, and there isn't much to say.