# Re: Mordell's Equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ and Perfect Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, open-problems, perfect-numbers

I have already tried a somewhat exhaustive search of the literature, but couldn't find anything close to the problem that I am working on.

My question is:  When does Mordell's Equation

$$y^2 = x^3 + K$$

have only FINITELY many solutions over the field of rational numbers, if we allow $K$ itself to be a rational number?

I've seen a "criterion" (i.e. a set of sufficient conditions) related to the class number of the (real/imaginary) quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{K})$, but it is limited only to $K$ being either 1 or 2 modulo 4.

[The actual "criterion" (as stated in the Japanese[?] paper that I allude to) is:

Mordell's equation $y^2 = x^3 + K$ has finitely many solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$ if

(1) $-K$ is not of the form $3t^2 + 1$ or $3t^2 - 1$; AND

(2) $K \equiv 1 (mod 4)$ or $K \equiv 2 (mod 4)$; AND

(3) $3$ does not divide the class number of the (real/imaginary) quadratic field $Q(\sqrt{K})$.]

Edit:  Please refer to this [hyperlink](http://www3.alpha-net.ne.jp/users/fermat/dioph54e.html) for more information as to the context of the previous "criterion".  These have since been refuted by Kevin Buzzard (@Kevin - thank YOU!).

Thanks to Kevin for pointing out some of the subtle errors in my original post, particularly in the third condition.  I was considering the case $K > 0$ (i.e. for real quadratic fields).

Now for the context:

Let

$$Y = W + Z$$

and

$$X = WZ$$

where $W$ and $Z$ are defined as:

$$W = I(p^k) = \frac{\sigma_{1}(p^k)}{p^k}$$

$$Z = I(m^2) = \frac{\sigma_{1}(m^2)}{m^2}$$

Let $$N = {p^k}{m^2}$$ be a perfect number.  (At this point, we don't have to distinguish between even or odd $N$ because the Euclid-Euler model for perfect numbers fits both cases.  For more details regarding this, please refer to this [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52851078/JIS-Dris-OPNPaper1-Major-Revision-04122011).)

We "know" that the exponent $k$ allows us to distinguish between even and odd $N$ in the sense that:

(1)  If $k$ = 1, then $N$ is even.

(2)  If $k$ > 1, then $N$ is odd.  (Again, refer to the [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52851078/JIS-Dris-OPNPaper1-Major-Revision-04122011) for more details.  There is also a related MathOverflow post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48203/on-sorlis-conjecture-re-opns-circa-2003).)

Thus, a (possibly) feasible and modern approach to the OPN problem (i.e. determining nonexistence or otherwise) will be to try establishing a finiteness result first (for particular values of $K$).

In other words, checking for finiteness of OPNs amounts to checking for finiteness of solutions for Mordell's equation

$$Y^2 = X^3 + K$$

for particular values of $K$.

And you will only have to check for values of $K$ in the range $[50, 399]$ (for a total of 350 elliptic curves), per the previous answer to this MathOverflow question.

$K$ falls in that range because the sum

$$Y = W + Z$$

is known to lie in the open interval $(57/20, 3)$.

Of course, the "juicy" implication is that:  If you will be able to find a condition (e.g. equation, inequality, etc.) relating $k$ to $K$ and you are also able to FURTHER show that the number of solutions to the corresponding Mordell equation $Y^2 = X^3 + K$ is finite FOR ALL SUCH $K$, then it would follow that there are only finitely many perfect numbers (odd AND even).

Disclaimer: This is a "naive" approach based on my current understanding of elliptic curve theory.  I am well-aware, of course, that the rationals are dense over the real numbers.  [Edit:  In addition, the abundancy indices and the abundancy outlaws are both dense over the rationals.]  Which is why I was kinda surprised that there is NO need to assume ("strict") rationality (i.e. $K \in \mathbb{Q}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$) for $K$ when checking for finiteness of solutions to Mordell's equation.

Comment: Are you really expecting a criterion simpler than the statement itself? I'm not sure you're going to get one!

Comment: Well, it seems the OP is in IT, and I think it's not surprising a non number theorist might expect a simple answer.

Comment: @Kevin, I do think there is such a criterion (although, the paper I allude to is in Japanese).  =)
@Kimball - your assumptions are correct.  =)

Comment: @Arnie: Diophantine equations are "hard". There will be other criteria, some unconditional, some conditional on the truth of some parts of the Birch--Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture. There may well be some easy criteria when $k$ is prime; one can do the descent and computer Selmer ranks sometimes. But the bottom line is that all these equivalent, or conditionally equivalent, criteria, for general $k$, will involve mathematics that you cannot explain to a high-school kid. You can get as fancy as you like but the bottom line is that you can ask a computer algebra package for the rank of the...

Comment: ...curve for any given explicit small k and you'll get an answer very quickly. You ask "when does the equation have finitely many solutions"---but this isn't really a mathematics question because you don't give a criterion which makes any given answer acceptable to you: e.g. clearly "it has finitely many solutions iff it has finitely many solutions" is not an acceptable answer, even though it's logically correct. How about "it has finitely many solns if the L-function doesn't vanish at 1". Is that any good? It sounds useless in practice! Why not just compute the solutions!

Comment: @Arnie: having said all that, there could be some analogue of Tunnell's theorem: perhaps there are some weight 3/2 modular forms kicking around such that the special value of the $L$-function is a coefficient of the form. It's not as simple as Tunnell's case becuase we're not dealing with quadratic twists so I don't think there would be a result that's as clean as his theorem, but perhaps for a given $k_0$ you could get a relatively easy criterion for all numbers of the form $k_0n^3$ if BSD is true.

Comment: @Kevin, my profuse thanks for your detailed response. As I am not an expert in elliptic curve theory, I would 
have to disclose what exact approach I am taking, and from where I am taking off. The (Japanese[?]) paper that 
I allude to in my previous comment states that Mordell's equation will have finitely many rational solutions 
iff (1) $−k$ is not of the form $(3t^2)+1$ or $(3t^2)−1$, (2) $k≡1(mod4)$ (xor) $k≡2(mod4)$, and (3) 3 does not 
divide the class number of the [real quadratic field] $Q(\sqrt{k})$. I was trying to see if there was a 
(more) general result...

Comment: @Arnie: I'm not sure you've stated the criterion correctly. In fact I'm quite confused. You implied in the question that the criterion in the paper only applied for $k=1$ or 2 mod 4. What you have written in the comment above seems to apply for all $k$ (in the sense that it seems to give information for all $k$). Furthermore condition (3) seems to imply that $k>0$ and condition (1) seems to imply that $k<0$ is the case of interest.

Comment: Let me also make some other comments. If one wants to prove a statement of the form "number of solutions is finite if and only if [some condition $C$ is true for $k$]" then the hard part of the proof will be proving that if $C$ fails then there are infinitely many solutions. This is exactly the part of BSD that we can't get to, because solving Diophantine equations is hard. In particular I'm saying any iff statement for $k$ should either be not too deep (i.e. basically equivalent), or should assume BSD, or should be amazing.

Comment: So, for example, the way you wrote your criterion, it seems to me that you're saying that if $k$ is 3 mod 4 then there will always be infinitely many solutions. I am not sure that this sort of statement is accessible. This is exactly the sort of statement that is super-hard to prove. It might be true, but I am a bit skeptical. In fact it's not even true is it---consider $k=7$.

Comment: Why don't you write the correct criterion in the statement of the question? That way people will understand much better what you are asking. As I have already said, currently a logically correct answer to the question is "number of solutions is finite iff number of solutions is finite".

Comment: @Kevin, editing my post now.

Comment: @Kevin, I will try to get hold of that Japanese(?) paper and will get back to you with an update ASAP.  (It is a bit hard to try searching for it using Google, etc. because of the differences in alphabetic characters [i.e. English vs. Nihongo].)  But that being said, my profuse thanks for taking the time out to read my post.  Your effort is appreciated!  =)

Comment: Arnie: the criterion you write is not correct. $k=7$ is a counterexample, at least according to my computer.

Comment: [$k=7$: only finitely many points, but $k$ isn't 1 or 2 mod 4]

Comment: Conditions such as the one on the class number usually are made to make the proof work. If the class number is divisibly by 3, on the other hand, then this does not mean that there are solutions, it just means that you have to work harder for solving the problem. 

Comment: @Kevin: I am still trying to get hold of the paper containing the result I alluded to. Will let you know ASAP. @Franz: Thanks for pointing that out. In particular, may I ask if there is a known closed-form for the class number of the real quadratic field $Q(\sqrt{k})$?

Comment: Arnie: you are living in a dream world. You cannot expect to find a wonderful simple criterion for this equation to have finitely many solutions. There are plenty of methods for computing class numbers of real quadratic fields. There are also plenty of methods for computing ranks of elliptic curves such as the one in your question. You are asking these questions but it's hard to believe that the answers can help you. Say for example that I just tell you some explicit formula whose answer is the class group---such formulas exist. What will you do now? 

Comment: I would worry more about the fact that I have given you a counterexample to the criterion you're claiming! 

Comment: @Arnie: I should clarify: there might be wonderful simple criteria---but they will depend on BSD being true.

Comment: @Kevin, for k = 7, does 3 not divide the class number of the (real) quadratic field $Q(\sqrt{k})$?

Comment: @Kevin, I did verify that the class number of $Q(\sqrt{7})$ is $1$, per WolframAlpha. However, it is still a problem for me to get hold of the paper I alluded to (e.g. I do not even recall the author's name nor the title of the paper). At any rate, I will get back to you with an update ASAP, earliest would be tomorrow.

Comment: @Arnie: you're barking up the wrong tree. I don't care what the class number is. $7$ isn't $1$ or $2$ mod 4, so (2) fails, so "(1) and (2) and (3)" fails regardless of the truth status of (3). So according to the "criterion" you're claiming, the curve should have infinitely many points. And my computer says it doesn't. Let me again stress that I am a bit skeptical about a genuine provable "iff" criterion of this form.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding.  

@Kevin, I see your point now.  I didn't realize that the "iff" mattered here. (Indeed, I was under the naive assumption that BSD would be proven ahead of any such "iff" criterion).  Notwithstanding, I still have not gotten hold of the Japanese paper I alluded to the other day.  I do believe however, given your counterexample, that the conditions given by (1), (2) and (3) are sufficient for showing that Mordell's equation has finitely many solutions.  

Editing my post now to clarify the context for the number-theory problem that I am considering.

Comment: The posted question presents an idea in the direction of showing there are finitely many perfect numbers.  However, the even perfect numbers correspond to Mersenne primes and it is a standard conjecture that there should be infinitely many such primes.  More precisely, there are heuristic predictions for the frequency of Mersenne primes and I think the data so far fit the heuristic at least up to an order of magnitude. Everyone expects there to be infinitely many even perfect numbers, so a strategy for proving there are just finitely many perfect numbers is suspicious. 

Comment: Or to put it in another way:  The fact that it is conjectured that there are infinitely many even perfect numbers contrasted to the "conjecture" that there are no OPNs is an instance of the "law of excluded middle" -- provided, that there is NO relationship (direct or indirect, explicit or implicit) between "the" $k$ and "the" $K$.  I will have to categorically state that I do not know how to check when a particular elliptic curve (corresponding to a particular value of $K$ for Mordell's equation) has finitely many solutions [although I am familiar with chord-tangent method... 

Comment: ... of generating new solutions from old.  Indeed, I have not checked for finiteness of solutions for any $K$ in the range I've given.  Nonetheless, I am convinced that the theory of perfect numbers can serve as a "baseline" for further developments in number theory (e.g. the Euclid-Euler model allows one to distinguish between the even and odd cases by looking at the "exponent" of the Mersenne and Euler primes, respectively.)  For more on this, you can have a look at http://arnienumbers.blogspot.com/2010/12/proof-for-sorlis-conjecture-on-odd.html.

Comment: That being said, thank you for your comment @KConrad.  Although, I will have to say, that I did state that you need to do two things in order to prove what I "conjectured":  (1)  Come up with a natural and/or suitable "relationship" between $k$ and $K$ (in the context of the theory of perfect numbers, crossing over to elliptic curve theory).  That is, give an interpretation for $K$ that naturally "relates" to the interpretation for $k$.  (2)  Check each resulting value of $K$ in the range implied by the "interpretation" you have given in (1).  If you can do both, the conjecture is proved.

Comment: @KConrad, in (2), I actually meant to say "Check for finiteness" when I said "Check each resulting value of $K$..." but I am guessing the context is clear enough...

Comment: @Arnie: your revised criterion is also not right; $K=2$ is a counterexample. I'm afraid that I can no longer take this criterion seriously: you firstly stated it as an iff criterion but neither implication is true, and furthermore you have given no hint of either a proof or a reference :-(

Comment: @Arnie: given an explicit elliptic curve, and a computer algebra package, you can easily check for yourself whether it has finitely or infinitely many points on it. You suggest that you're interested in 350 elliptic curves. About half of them will have finitely many solutions and the other half will have infinitely many (to a very rough first order approximation). I hope this information helps somehow! If you actually care about which curves have infinitely many points then I urge you to learn how to use a standard package like mwrank (within SAGE) to compute these things yourself. 

Comment: @Kevin, my profuse thanks for providing the second counterexample!  That being said, I will (of course) still be interested in a theorem/lemma (or any result for that matter) which contains a set of sufficient conditions for finiteness.

Lastly, please do try to look at http://www3.alpha-net.ne.jp/users/fermat/dioph54e.html when you get the time.  I got that link just now.  I don't really know if there is a problem with my PC (e.g. malware, network issues, etc.), but I have tried searching for that webpage numerous times ever since I saw it.  Moving forward, we can now take note of the URL. =)

Comment: @Kevin, I forgot to say:  Thank you also about the CAS [i.e. Computer Algebra System] idea.  Although, I prefer doing everything by hand first, then verifying if my calculations are correct using a CAS.  WolframAlpha is one (online) CAS that I consider very useful for doing mathematics this way.

Comment: Update: I just saw this MathWorld link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MordellCurve.html. My apologies to everyone if I didn't bother to check. But given that the Mordell curve only has a finite number of solutions when $k$ is an integer, (and given Felipe's answer below), I do see where the "weakness" of my argument is: It's in passing from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ that we do indeed have to "discover" a specific relationship between "the" k and "the" K. Indeed, I would think that a full characterization for odd numbers of the form $N = {p^k}{m^2}$ to be perfect would be required. 

Comment: Arnie: please stop using MO as a place to announce your work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, if you replace $k$ by $d^6k$ you get another equation such that the corresponding sets of rational solutions are in bijection. So, you might as well assume that $k$ is an integer. I don't think there is a simple, crisp criterion for the equation to have finitely many solutions. Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer predicts that this is the case if and only if the $L$-function of the elliptic curve does not vanish at $s=1$ and the "if" part is known (Coates-Wiles). There is no shortage of literature on that.

Comment: @Felipe, thanks a lot!  On a side note, BSD is one of the "deepest" conjectures in number theory (i.e. Millenium Problem) but I am actually working on something which is somewhat "unrelated" -- and it's the OPN conjecture.

Comment: You might as well also assume that $k \not\equiv 0 \bmod 27$, because the curves $y^2 = x^3 + k$ and $y^2=x^3−3^{-3}k$ are isogenous and thus have the same rank. 

Comment: Thanks Noam!  Any references in the literature for that?  (My apologies, I am still in the process of self-studying elliptic curve theory...)

Comment: @Arnie: if you ever need some non trivial consequence of BSD conjecture in your research, you might be interested in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149815/automorphisms-of-the-l-function-associated-to-an-elliptic-mathbbq-curve where I give a few ideas about the weak version thereof (equality of the two kinds of ranks). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another reason why there's unlikely to be a simple answer, unless you can find a simple answer to another question that appears to be very deep. You can try to do a descent to compute the $p$-Selmer group for some small prime $p$, and if that succeeds, you will have computed the rank. But in computing the $2$-Selmer group, you'll need to know the $3$-part of the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-k})$. Similarly, in computing the $3$-Selmer group, you'll need to know the $2$-part of the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{k})$. I'm not aware of any elementary conditions on $k$, for example, congruence conditions, which would let you determine the ranks of those parts of those ideal class groups. The situation is very different for the curves $E_k:y^2=x^3+kx$, since here there is a rational $2$-torsion point, so the $2$-Selmer group can be computed without working in an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. That's why, for example, there are some special cases such as $k$ prime and congruent to 7 or 11 modulo 16 for which one knows that the Mordell-Weil rank is zero, so $E_k(\mathbb{Q})$ is finite.

Answer (score -3):

A search for "Mordell's equation finiteness" shows:

www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/mordell.pdf

Comment: Which part of that file answers the question that was asked?

Comment: @Igor, my profuse thanks for providing that link, but I did already take a look at that one (even before making this MO post), and as I have said (and as KConrad did note), there do not seem to be much in that PDF file w.r.t. the number-theory problem that I am trying to solve.

@KConrad - thanks for pointing that out! =)