# What is the rank of the Mordell equation $y^2 = x^3 - 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

The mordell equation $E$ defined by $y^2 = x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is known to have only one non-trivial integer solution $P = (3,5)$ from [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf). However, the rank of Mordell-Weil group $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is not zero because formulas known since the time of Bachet show that $P$ has infinite order.

How can we compute the rank of $E$ without using MAGMA or the BSD conjecture? I'd be happy to see an argument by 3-descent.

The torsion subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is known to be trivial.

Comment: it seems the answer is "no" --- http://mathoverflow.net/a/202080/11260

Comment: That's about a criterion for a curve in the family $y^2 = x^3 + k$
to have rank zero.  It can be much sipmler for a single curve in this family,
which is what this question is asking (with $k=-2$).

Comment: What might be a *trivial* integer solution?

Comment: Hm, good point.  Often for such equations there are trivial solutions
with one variable equal zero; e.g. $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ has trivial solutions
$(x,y) = (-1,0)$ (2-torsion) and $(0,\pm 1)$ (3-torsion), and also
the nontrivial solutions $(2,\pm 3)$ (6-torsion) and no others.
But $y^2 = x^3 - 2$ has no integer solutions with $xy=0$.
There is the trivial element ("point at infinity") 
of the group of rational points, but that point is not integral.

Answer (score 12):

Entering the curve's coefficient vector **[0,0,0,0,-2]**
into **mwrank** (which must be what MAGMA uses),
we find that the rank is $1$ and the group of rational points
is generated by $(3,5)$ (up to torsion, but **gp** quickly reports
that the torsion is trivial).  Now **mwrank** uses $2$-descent,
which means that you need either the arithmetic of the pure cubic field 
${\bf Q}(\root 3 \of 2)$ or some reduction theory of binary quartic forms. 
It can surely be done also using descent via the $3$-isogenies between 
$E$ and the curve $y^2 = x^3 + 54$, which will require only the arithmetic of
${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-2}\,)$ and ${\bf Q}(\sqrt6\,)$; but though that's in principle
easier than $2$-descent it would still take much longer to do by hand than
to press the **mwrank** button.  But perhaps it's done somewhere as an exercise
in a textbook or lecture notes.

Comment: I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find anything for 3-descent of this particular elliptic curve. I don't know why one would do 2-descent as it's a prime of bad reduction.

Comment: 3 is also a prime of bad reduction . . .
$$ $$
In general 2-descents are much easier than 3-descents; bad reduction at 2
(or 3) doesn't really affect this.  The reason that this curve is 
a natural candidate for 3-descent is that it has a rational 3-isogeny, 
so you need only work over quadratic number fields, not octic which 
would be the usual situation.  A quick skim through Dickson's *History*
finds nothing on this particular curve, so possibly Mordell might have been the first to work it out, and you might try searching through his works.

Comment: Also, the curve is simple enough that you can also
look it up in LMFDB http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1728/o/3
$-$ but of course the information there was also computed by 2-descent,
and thus ultimately using **mwrank**.

Answer (score 12):

You could have a look at this paper:

[M. Stoll, *On the arithmetic of the curves  $y^2 = x^\ell + A$, II*;
J. Number Theory **93**, 183-206 (2002).](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X01927271)

Corollary 2.1 says that for $A = -2$, one gets a rank bound of
$1$ plus twice the $3$-rank of the class group of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{6})$.
So it only remains to verify that the class number of this field is not
divisible by $3$ (in fact, it is $1$).

The method is $(1-\zeta_3)$-descent, which is pretty close to a $3$-isogeny
descent. Apart from the class number determination, no computation is
necessary; it all follows from theoretical considerations.