# Looking for an appropriate reference(s) for two conjectures on odd perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, conjectures, perfect-numbers

(I apologize in advance if this question is unsuitable for MO.  If so, please let me know and I will migrate it to MSE.)

Let $\sigma(M)$ be the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $M$.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$.

A number $N$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

Euler proved that an *odd* perfect number $N$ must have the form $N=q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  We call $q$ the *Euler prime* of $N$.

Here are my questions:

> **(1)** Who is credited with making the conjecture that $q$ is the largest prime factor of $N$?
>
> **(2)** Additionally, to whom should I attribute the conjecture that $k=1$?  Should it be Descartes, Frenicle, or Sorli?

(**Added September 28 2016** For **(2)**: In an edit to this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48203), it is stated that (per Beasley), "Dris $\ldots$ refers to Descartes’ and Frenicle’s claim (that $k=1$) as Sorli’s conjecture; Dickson has documented Descartes’s conjecture as occurring in a letter to Marin Mersenne in 1638, with Frenicle’s subsequent observation occurring in 1657".  As commented by Gerry, one would need to double-check Dickson's *History of Number Theory* to verify Beasley's statements.)

Comment: I don't know, but have you looked at Dickson's History of Number Theory?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, will do.  Thanks for pointing out that reference!  =)

Comment: Doesn't your edit of 18 September 2013 on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48203/on-sorlis-conjecture-re-opns-circa-2003 answer your (2) here? [and even if it doesn't, shouldn't you have at least linked to it?]

Comment: My apologies for the oversight Gerry, doing so now.  (By the way, I hope this question does not duplicate that other one...)